# Spring boot won't connect to Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn Spring Boot with a tutorial. I have the code and the database, but I keep getting a Hibernate ERROR whenever I try to connect the two...

This is the Error I get:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)


2022-08-04 19:23:59.263  INFO 13108 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1746 ms
2022-08-04 19:23:59.463  INFO 13108 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-04 19:24:00.560 ERROR 13108 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

I have the dependency set up in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The StudentService

```
    @Service
public class StudentService {
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return List.of(
                new Student(
                        1L,
                        "Mariam",
                        "mariam.jamal@gmail.com",
                        LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 5),
                        21
                )
        );
    }
}
```

And the StudentController class

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasouce.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernat.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what's the problem or what I can do to improve it. I googled, but only found "the password not filled in" (which is not the case) and "the application.properties not being in the resources folder" (which they are...)

Thank you so much already for looking through it and if I can clarify anything, I am happy to do so.

Edit: sorry for posting it as pictures I replaced everything but the error code if I should change that too just tell me

If I am correct, the version of the PostgreSQL is 14.4 the text from the pg_hba.config:

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#   


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Comment: There is no `psql` database there is the `psql` client that connects to Postgres database. Change your title accordingly.

Comment: Please do not provide images of code. They can't be searched or compiled. Copy/paste your code as actual text and format it as code.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: What does your application.properties look like?

Comment: To your question add Postgres version as well as text(not image) of `pg_hba.conf` file. From error looks like it could be SCRAM/md5 password issue.

Comment: Hi sorry for the pictures, I thought it would just be easier...
I also added the PostgreSQL version number and the pg_hba.config file. If I missed something, I'll be happy to add it aswell! Thank you for telling me

Comment: Do you see any messages in the PostgreSQL log file about connection/authentication failures?  Does Hikari have its own log files you can look in?

Comment: No the console for the PostgreSQL doesn't say anything, probably because the connection doesn't go through from the SpringSQL part? and I wouldn't know about Hikari files, a quick google search doesn't tell me anything about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by now. The problem was that I wrote `hibernat` instead of `hibernate` in the application.properties...